# Rails 3 Routes change RESTFUL URL action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

How can I change ':action=>"index"' to ':action=>"list"'?

I'm using ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 3.1.3.

BACKGROUND:
I'm fiddling with bitcoin-central. When I go to htt*://localhost:3000/admin/pending_transfers, an missing templates error occurs. It's because of active scaffold's bug. To render correctly, it have to use "list" action. I can fix it by copying list.html.erb to index.html.erb, but its solution seems dirty.

Here's my part of rake routes

```
Machida-no-MacBook-Air:bitcoin-central machidahiroaki$ rake routes | grep index
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
                                     invoices GET    /invoices(.:format)                                                     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"invoices"}
                                user_yubikeys GET    /user/yubikeys(.:format)                                                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"yubikeys"}
                           user_bank_accounts GET    /user/bank_accounts(.:format)                                           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"bank_accounts"}
                                 user_tickets GET    /user/tickets(.:format)                                                 {:action=>"index", :controller=>"tickets"}
                            account_transfers GET    /account/transfers(.:format)                                            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"transfers"}
                               account_trades GET    /account/trades(.:format)                                               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"trades"}
                             account_invoices GET    /account/invoices(.:format)                                             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"invoices"}
                         account_trade_orders GET    /account/trade_orders(.:format)                                         {:action=>"index", :controller=>"trade_orders"}
                          admin_announcements GET    /admin/announcements(.:format)                                          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/announcements"}
                               admin_yubikeys GET    /admin/yubikeys(.:format)                                               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/yubikeys"}
                           admin_static_pages GET    /admin/static_pages(.:format)                                           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/static_pages"}
                             admin_currencies GET    /admin/currencies(.:format)                                             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/currencies"}
                                admin_tickets GET    /admin/tickets(.:format)                                                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/tickets"}
                               admin_comments GET    /admin/comments(.:format)                                               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/comments"}
                      admin_pending_transfers GET    /admin/pending_transfers(.:format)                                      {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/pending_transfers"}
                admin_user_account_operations GET    /admin/users/:user_id/account_operations(.:format)                      {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/account_operations"}
                                  admin_users GET    /admin/users(.:format)                                                  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/users"}
```

Here's my routes.rb

```
BitcoinBank::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :invoices, :only => [:index, :new, :create, :show, :destroy]

  resource :user, :only => [:edit, :update] do
    get :ga_otp_configuration
    post :reset_ga_otp_secret
    put :update_password
    get :edit_password

    resources :yubikeys, :only => [:index, :create, :destroy]
    resources :bank_accounts, :only => [:index, :create, :destroy]
    resources :tickets do
      resources :comments, :only => :create
      member do
        post :close
        post :reopen
        post :solve
      end
    end
  end

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

  # These routes need some loving :/
  resource :chart, :path => "charts", :only => [] do
    get :price
  end

  resource :account, :only => [:show] do
    match '/balance/:currency',
      :action => 'balance',
      :as => 'balance',
      :only => :get

    get :deposit
    get :pecunix_deposit_form

    resources :transfers, :only => [:index, :new, :create, :show] 

    resources :trades, 
      :only => [:index]

    resources :invoices

    resources :trade_orders, :only => [:index, :new, :create, :destroy] do
      post :activate
    end
  end

  match "/s/:name" => "static_pages#show", :as => :static

  match '/third_party_callbacks/:action',
    :controller => :third_party_callbacks

  namespace :admin do
    %w{ announcements yubikeys static_pages currencies tickets comments }.each { |r| resources(r.to_sym) {as_routes} }

    resources :pending_transfers do
      as_routes

      member do
        post :process_tx
      end
    end

    resources :users do
      as_routes

      member do
        get :balances
      end

      resources :account_operations do
        as_routes
      end
    end

    match '/balances', :to => 'informations#balances', :as => :balances
  end

  match '/qrcode/:data.png' => 'qrcodes#show', :as => :qrcode

  match '/order_book' => 'trade_orders#book'

  match '/trades' => 'trades#all_trades'

  match '/ticker' => 'trades#ticker'

  match '/economy' => 'informations#economy', :as => :economy

  match '/support' => 'informations#support', :as => :support

  root :to => 'informations#welcome'
end
```

---

I've deleted list.html.erb on application view directory and put this code on application_controller.rb

```
  def index
    render :action => 'list'
  end
```

It is not called. And template missing error occures.

---

When I put the code above on users_controller, I got this error.

```
NoMethodError in Admin/users#index

Showing /Users/machidahiroaki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/active_scaffold-3.2.20/frontends/default/views/_list_messages.html.erb where line #21 raised:

undefined method `items' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #21):

18:         </div>
19:         <% end -%>
20:       </div>
21:       <p id="<%= empty_message_id %>" class="empty-message" <%= ' style="display:none;" '.html_safe unless @page.items.empty? %>>
22:         <%= as_(active_scaffold_config.list.no_entries_message) %>
23:       </p>
24:     </td>
Trace of template inclusion: /Users/machidahiroaki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/active_scaffold-3.2.20/frontends/default/views/_list.html.erb, /Users/machidahiroaki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/active_scaffold-3.2.20/frontends/default/views/_list_with_header.html.erb, /Users/machidahiroaki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/active_scaffold-3.2.20/frontends/default/views/list.html.erb

Rails.root: /Volumes/G-DRIVE_slim/Development/bitcoin-central

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:94:in `index'
config/initializers/monkey_patches.rb:8:in `call'
```

Comment: In index action, you can say `render :action => 'list'`. This will render the list.html.erb template

Comment: I've deleted index.html.erb and put `render :action => 'list'` on application_controller.rb. but I got missing template error.

Comment: I put `
  def index
    render :action => 'list'
  end` on application_controller.rb, but It seems searching index.html.erb.